# Do I must create my own server side to use google cloud messaging?

Tags: android, server-side, google-cloud-messaging

Ok, before you flame me alive...

I mean, is there is a platform (like parse.com for manage data base server side),

thats enable client side developers without server side prior knowledge (like me),

to easily work with or build the server side of GCM (google cloud messaging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com) is a very popular solution.
2. [Core Push](http://www.corepush.com/) is another, but maybe not open to public yet
3. Can't vouch for it but [parse](https://parse.com/plans) looks free at least for lower push volumes.

Comment: "Urban Airship" charging min 200$ per month. And "Core Push" is indeed close to public yet. Do you know any other for free?

Comment: I mentioned parse.com in my question, and didn't know that thay also taking care of the GCM server side for me... 10x, I will check them now.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has recently released a GCM push notification service for Android to handle the server side complexity. The service is called AirBop - www.airbop.com. It's free to try and use for a small number of devices. I just thought I'd mention it as another potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [Onesignal.com](http://onesignal.com) it's free and works like a charm. It can also push to multiple platforms at the same time and you can easily make user sections.